# Get grid view items ifrom onitemclick

Tags: java, android, gridview

i want to set events to onItemClickListener of my gridview items, so that each item opens a fragment. i would want to use a switch but getItemId() does not exist, any ideas... am new to android
thank you;

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) { 

        // hw do i use switch on the different items?

    }
});
```

Comment: You can do based on position

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) { 
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            // first item in grid
            break;
        case 1:
            // second item in grid
            break;
        case 2:
            // third item in grid
            break;  
        ...     
    }
}
```